# Simulate right Shift+Ctrl with SendKeys.Send()

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I'm trying to Send right <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to my `RichTextBox`. But as default it sends the left keys.

```
SendKeys.Send("^+");
```

Is there anyway to simulate right <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?

Comment: `{RSHIFT}+` should work right?

Comment: @kevintjuh93 `{RSHIFT}` throws `Keyword "RSHIFT" is not valid.`

Comment: That is weird, according to several sources it should work. Anyway, you are probably going to need `PostMessage` now. Can you also tell me why you need to send these keys to your RTB?

Comment: @kevintjuh93 Because RichTextBox doesnt support text direction. it only has RightToLeft which doesn't work well for RightToLeft languages

Comment: Where are you placing this code?

Comment: @kevintjuh93 In `mainform_load()` after `rchNote.Select();`

Comment: I suggest looking for `SendMessage/PostMessage` to send keys to the `rchNote.Handle`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can check the [Virtual-Key Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx) where the code for the right shift key and right control key is

```
VK_RSHIFT   0xA1
VK_RCONTROL 0xA3
```

So you can do like

```
public const int VK_RSHIFT  = 0xA1;
public const int VK_RCONTROL= 0xA3;
```

or

You can try like this:

```
SendKeys.Send(VirtualKeyCode.VK_RSHIFT);
```

or else you can use the [Keys Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies key codes and modifiers.

which specifies

RShiftKey for the right shift key and RControlKey for the right control key.

or as commented by kevintjuh93

```
SendKeys.Send("^({RSHIFT}+)")
```

Comment: Don't you have the `Keys` class in C#?

Comment: So how should I send keys with these codes. something like `SendKeys.Send("0xA1" + "0xA3");`?

Comment: @kevintjuh93:- Yes there is, updated my answer with that.

Comment: For `SendKeys.Send` you probably need this: `{RSHIFT}+`

Comment: @AlexJolig:- Update my answer!

Comment: Doesn't `SendKeys.Send` require a string as input?

Comment: Also, does he want both `right` keys or just `right shift`?

Comment: @kevintjuh93:- Not sure if OP wants both the right keys, but added that just to give an idea.

Comment: `^({RSHIFT}+)` throws 'Keyword "RSHIFT" is not valid' error